# How to define the following function rigorously?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

let $D=\{f \mid f:\mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ (the set of all functions taking the positive integers into the positive integers) and $E=\{f \mid f: \mathbb{Z}^{+} \rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$.  Want to show $|E| = |D|$.

Clearly $E\subset D$.  Now I define $F:D \rightarrow E$ such that if $f \in D$ then $F(f)$ is the infinite sequence such that there are $f(1)$ number of $1$'s followed by a $0$, then $f(2)$ number of $1$'s followed by a $0$, etc.  For example, if $i_{D}$ is the identity map in $D$, then $F(i_{D})=(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,...)$.  We can check that $F$ is indeed an injective function.  From here we apply Cantor-bernstein to show the cardinalities are the same.

My question is why is the function $F$ well-defined and how does one rigourously define it? I'm looking for some rigourous explanation - I was wondering whether it could be done using the principle of recursion.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: For me your solution looks very good and is rigorous enough. A small technical point: $E$ is not a subset of $D$ (basically $0$ is not positive number), but this can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define:
$$A_f=\{n+\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \mid n \in \Bbb{Z}^+\}$$
Then, define $F(f)$ as follows:
$$F(f)(n)= \begin{cases} 0 & n\in A_f\\ 1 & n\notin A_f\end{cases}$$
You can check this definition of $F(f)$ behaves exactly like the one you gave.

EDIT:

What follows is a possible definition using the recursion principle. Define $g:\Bbb{Z}^+ \times \Bbb{Z} \times \{0,1\} \to \Bbb{Z}^+ \times \Bbb{Z} \times \{0,1\} $ as follows:
$$g((x,y,z))=\begin{cases}(x, y-1, 1) & y>0\\ (x+1, f(x+1), 0) &y\leq 0\end{cases}$$
Now set: $$\begin{cases}(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,f(1),0)\\ (x_{n+1},y_{n+1},z_{n+1})=g((x_n,y_n,z_n))  & n\geq 0\end{cases}$$
You can check that $F(f)(n)=z_n$ $\forall n \ge 1$.

Comment: I think in your definition of $A_{f}$ you meant $n+\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$.  Thank you nonetheless

Comment: @SaranWrap OK I have fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(k) = k + \sum_{1 \le j\le k} f(j)$.  Since $S(n)$ is a nonnegative integer with $S(0) = 0$ and $S(n) < S(n+1)$, for each nonnegative integer $m$ there is a unique $n$ with
$S(n) \le m < S(n+1)$.  Then $F(f)(m) = 0$ if $m = S(n+1)-1$, otherwise $F(f)(m)=1$.